# Bug - Slideout Menu Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mobile, navigation

I am attempting to create a slideout menu for this site:

http://newdigitalguru.com/kckarchitects/

The menu works on every page but the homepage, and I can't seem to figure out why. The script is loading, and it will apply the "open" class, but it immediately removes it and gives it the "close" class and then it doesn't work any more. I followed this tutorial:

http://www.dzyngiri.com/responsive-menu-using-trunk-js/

Comment: can you add a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

On your homepage, you have the following code within your HTML (in a `<script>` tag towards the end):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var items = $('.slideRight, .slideLeft');
    var content = $('.container');

    var open = function() {
        $(items).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
    }

    var close = function() { 
        $(items).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    }

    $('#navToggle').click(function(){
        if (content.hasClass('open')) {$(close)}
        else {$(open)}
    });

    content.click(function(){
        if (content.hasClass('open')) {$(close)}
    });
});
```

Not sure if this code was placed here to debug or test something else, but it's essentially breaking your sliding menu. If you remove or comment out this code, the homepage works as expected.

You'll notice that this code only exists on the homepage.